# Не работают стили на сайте

Tags: css

Сейчас я осваиваю замечательную связку FlexBox + Less. Вроде всё делаю правильно, но сайт почему-то не тянется во всю ширину экрана.
  Вот ссылка на сайт на Яндекс диске https://yadi.sk/d/vBKLKTnEBHcEpg
  Проверял css файлы вроде всё нормально.
 В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Сайт тянется на всю ширину экрана. Скриншот: http://bit.ly/2KRpnTr . В чем именно вопрос?

Comment: Скриншот: http://bit.ly/30t3Be9

Comment: Тогда я немного изменю вопрос. Сайт действительно тянется на всю ширину экрана, а вот картинка нет. Кажется я понял. Нужно картинке приписать свойство, чтобы она тянулась на всю ширину экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сайт действительно тянется на всю ширину экрана, а вот картинка нет

1) У Вас для тега `<body>` задано свойство `display:flex`, из-за чего его дочерние элементы выстраиваются в строку. Нужно убрать это свойство `display: flex`; Или добавить свойство `flex-direction: column;` (задавать подобные свойства для тега `body` неразумно. Лучше создать внутри еще один тег типа `<div class="wrapper">` и работать с ним)

2) Для тега `header` у Вас ограничена ширина свойством `max-width: 1260px;`. Его также нужно убрать.

3) Картинка задана фоном через свойство `background`. Чтобы фон занимал всю картинку, нужно задать размер по ширине 100%: `background: url('../img/background.png') top left / 100% no-repeat;`

4) Для тега `<body>` нужно убрать отступы `margin: 0`

Результат: https://fex.net/s/toa7sof

Comment: hisbvdis Вы абсолютно всё разложили по полочкам. Результат впечатляет !!! Скажите, а какие курсы вы учили?  И как я понял для других секций сайта тоже нужно создавать div с классом wrapper и уже с ними работать ?

Comment: Здравствуйте hisbvdis. Большое спасибо вам за ответ :-)  Обычно при простой вёрстке сайтов без использования flex. Верстают по такому правилу.  Для каждой секции создают обёртывающий див с классом wrapper и уже с ним работают. Вот как на рисунке https://i.imgur.com/aeMQuAN.png  Верно ли такое правило при использовании flex технологии?  С уважением Сергей Кондулуков

Comment: (В): Скажите, а какие курсы вы учили?  (О): Да никаких конкретных курсов не проходил, почитываю в интернете материалы. Со временем запоминается.

Comment: (В): И как я понял для других секций сайта тоже нужно создавать div с классом wrapper и уже с ними работать? (О): Не очень понятен вопрос. Если речь идет о работе с Flexbox, то свойство `display: flex` стоит применять к родительскому элементу, дочерними элементами которого будем манипулировать. Это не обязательно должен быть тег с классом `wrapper`.

Comment: (В): Обычно при простой вёрстке сайтов без использования flex. Верстают по такому правилу. Для каждой секции создают обёртывающий див с классом wrapper и уже с ним работают (О): Всё очень относительно. `wrapper` (кстати, его называют и по-другому) в показанном Вами примере обычно используют как центровщик контента внутри элемента. Он уместен в тех ситуациях, когда фон должен рястягиваться (фон мы задаём для `section`), а контент центрироваться. Если ситуация другая, просто в холостую добавлять еще один вложенный элемент `wrapper` смысла может и не быть.

Comment: (В): Верно ли такое правило при использовании flex технологии? (О): Снова-таки, если речь идет об элементе, который центрирует контент, от этого никуда не деться. И вполне можно использовать вместе.

Answer (score 0):

С BODY надо убрать `display: flex;`

Comment: Станислав в этом то вся и фишка что я верстаю на флексах. Тут нужно искать какое-то другое решение.